# auto sms when user is busy

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm a Objective-C / iPhone newbie. I want to develop an app that would automatically send an SMS message when the user is busy. I don't know how to go about it, please help me.

Comment: Why on earth would the APIs allow you to do that? With premium rate SMS services, that opens a massive hole for scamming users by sending messages without their consent.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send an SMS message without user interaction on the iPhone using the public APIs. The only supported way to do it is using the MFMessageComposeViewController class.

There may be a way if you're developing for jailbroken devices (I don't know anything about that), or you could have the program contact some sort of web service that would send the SMS message for you (i.e. the message would come from the service, not the device).

Comment: can u able guide me in using MFMessageComposeViewController class.

Comment: Follow [Apple's tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010416-SW1). In short, you check the `canSendText` class method to see if you even can send SMS, then create an instance, set a delegate, fill in the properties, and use `presentModalViewController:animated:` to show the dialog. When your delegate's `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:` is called, use `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` to close the dialog.